# Prefill prompt with existing answer when using ruby's Highline#ask

Tags: ruby

I'm getting input from a user using Ruby's Highline gem.
I'm asking the following

```
note = ask("Enter a note for this entry: ")
```

This is fine, but If the user edits the entry
I want to populate the prompt with their existing answer for this question so that it can be edited directly instead of entering it again.

Something like:

```
note = ask("Enter a note for this entry: ", :current => note)

# Output:    
Enter a note for this entry: the current note_
```

Comment: I am also interested in a solution

Answer (score 1):

A little bit too late, but:

The best solution i found for this problem was to use the `completion` attribute in the `ask` block.
So when you write the following code:

```
input = "Foobar" #default
loop do
    input = ask("Input: ") { |q| q.completion = [input]; q.readline = true }
end
```

You end up with this

```
Input: Fo<hit tab>
Input: Foobar
```

In every iteration you update the `completion` so you can easily get the input from your last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the highline gem, but the documentation for the ask method indicates it takes an optional block. I think this is how you would do it:

```
note = ask("Enter a note for this entry: ") { |q| q.default = "Default Answer" }
```

Comment: Hi @Derek the :default option is used to set the default answer returned if the user finishes the question leaving their answer blank, it does not pre-fill the prompt with that so it can be edited

Comment: ah, yes, I see that. I missed that requirement somehow.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything in the highline API for this. I tried writing to stdin manually, but once written, that text is immutable. Hmph...